# How do I get the name of the newest file via the Terminal?

Tags: shell, command-line, keyboard-maestro

I'm trying to create a macro for [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) for OS X doing the following:

1. Get name of newest file in a directory on my disk based on date created;
2. Paste the text "newest file: " plus the name of the newest file.

One of its options is to "Execute a shell script", so I thought that would do it for 1. After Googling around a bit I came up with this:

```
cd /path/to/directory/
ls -t | head -n1
```

This sorts it right, and returns the first filename. However, it also seems to includes a line break, which I do not want. As for 2: I can output the text "newest file: " with a different action in the app, and paste the filename behind that. But I'm wondering if you can't return "random text" + the outcome of the `ls` command.

So my question is: can I do this only using the `ls` command? And how do I get *just* the name of the latest file without any linebreaks or returns?

Comment: To get the random text you could do something like: `head -c 12 /dev/urandom | base64`. Oh, wait, you mean *arbitrary* text. Sorry, I was confused.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you're already using pipes, just throw another one in there:

```
ls -t | head -n1 |awk '{printf("newest file: %s",$0)}'
```

(Note that the "printf" does not include a '\n' at the end; that gets rid of the linebreak)

Edit:

With Arkku's suggestion to exit awk after the first line, it looks like:

```
ls -t | awk '{printf("newest file: %s",$0);exit}'
```

Comment: Why use `head -n1` at all when you could just `exit` from awk after the first line?

Comment: Thanks. how do I save it into a variable instead of printing it?

Answer (score 4):

```
cd /path/to/directory/
echo -n "random text goes here" $(ls -t | head -n1)
```

If you want, you can add more text on the end in the same way.

Comment: Thanks! This still had the return for some reason in the app, even though the -n didn't show it in the Terminal itself. But the echo followed by a command will come in handy for some other things as well :)

Answer (score 4):

Using output of `ls` is bad practice.

`find -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -n 1`

Comment: Why's using `ls` output a bad practice? Not disagreeing, just curious about the reasoning. Concerns about code injection?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in bash in a single statement like so:

```
echo -n "newest file: $(ls -t |head -n1)"
```

You can also remove that newline without `echo`:

```
ls -t |head -n1 |tr -d '\n'
```

Make sure `ls` doesn't output colors to non-tty streams (i.e. specify color by `ls --color=never` or `ls --color=auto` or not at all).

The `ls` solution will output files of *any* kind sorted by modification time. If you want only regular files or if you don't want directories then you can use `find` and `xargs`:

```
echo -n "newest file: $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |xargs -0 ls -t)"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it with only `ls`. However, as `echo` is generally built into the shell, it doesn't really add any overhead into the script. To get just the name of the file, I'd suggest:

```
echo -n "newest: $(ls -t1 | head -n1)"
```

If, for some reason, you really want to eliminate the `head`, then I suppose you could go for something like:

```
ls -t1 | ( read n; echo -n "newest: $n")
```

(`read` is built into the shell, `head` isn't.)

Note that these solutions do not recurse into subdirectories, since that was not specified in the question. In fact, subdirectories may be printed as the newest "file".

Comment: So, someone downvoted this (and some other answers) over 7 years later. I'd like to point out that this answer was posted mainly to answer the precise question "can I do this only using the `ls` command" (the accepted answer using `awk`, to which I contributed a suggestion, was already posted). It is not my fault if this doesn't answer some other question, even if the question turns up in search results.