# How to download latest file from SFTP server with Paramiko without using a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to get the most recent file from an SFTP server without using a loop as the number of files in the directory is thousands (and growing). The file names takes the following format: `filename_date.xml` (where `filename` can be any name and `date` is in the format `yyyymmdd_hh.mm.ss`).

According to the docs `listdir()` and `listdir_attr()` return a list of all files in arbitrary order so this isn't much help.

EDIT:
Further to the above I cannot execute shell commands, if I try to run a script using `exec_command` I get `This service allows sftp connections only.`.

Comment: This isn't a paramiko limitation, it's a SFTP limitation. See the spec at https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13 -- the operations it documents are all the operations that exist.

Answer (score 1):

There's no better way using a pure SFTP protocol.

For an example of implementation, see:
[How to download only the latest file from SFTP server with Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30626615/850848)

---

You would have to use another interface to retrieve the name of the latest file.

For example, if you have a shell access:

- You can use some smart command like in:
  [How do I get the name of the newest file via the Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2838475/850848)
- Execute it with Paramiko:
  [python paramiko run command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9470584/850848)
- And then use the obtained name for SFTP download.

Or you can create web service (web page) on the server that returns the name of the latest file.

Comment: If one controls the server, can just have it maintain a symlink to the latest file; considerably less trouble than setting up a web page, and keeps everything over just one protocol (which is pertinent if the SSH server for which we're using the SFTP subsystem is configured not to honor `shell` or `exec` requests).

Comment: Unfortunately I can only run SFTP commands, trying to execute shell commands returns `This service allows sftp connections only.`

Comment: OK, then my first sentence stands: *"There's no better way using a pure SFTP protocol."*